# How to use %exclude macro properly in rpmbuild SPEC files?

Tags: linux, configuration-files, rpm, rpmbuild

Consider the following in a SPEC file:

```
%files
%defattr(-,bubba,users,-)
...
%attr(-,root,users) %{_localstatedir}/foo/
%config %attr(-,root,root) %{_localstatedir}/foo/blah.crap
```

I want to include all files under `foo` but also specifically mark `blah.crap` as a config file (and its permissions may not match `foo`'s). Doing this causes rpmbuild to complain that the file is listed twice.

I tried to add the following between the last two lines above:

```
%exclude %{_localstatedir}/foo/blah.crap
```

However, this seems to permanently override any other inclusion, because, despite the fact that the next `%config` line ought to include the file (now as a config file), `blah.crap` does *not* get installed when I install the RPM.

So what's the right way to do this? Just ignoring the warning from rpmbuild is a BS answer, as is "just make a list of all files in `foo` instead of listing the whole directory".

Comment: The two things you rejected out of hand are the only answers I'm aware of for this problem.

Comment: @EtanReisner if I simply ignore the warning, what is the behavior of the RPM? Is the file treated as a config file, is the behavior dependent on the order of how it's "listed twice", or what?

Comment: Good question, I don't know. You'd want to dump the resulting rpm file to find out (and test different orders, etc.) to know for sure. But it looks like in rpm 4.4.2.3's source it looks like the entries are merged (and that seems to still be true in rpm 4.9.1.3).

Answer (score 1):

The best solution is to create a file manifest using find(1) in %install and used sed(1) to add %config or otherwise filter the manifest to taste.